# How to convert nii images to 2D image?

Tags: python, image

I have stack of images (100 slices) in nii format, and I want to convert them to 2D png format in order to feed them to 2D model.

```
import nibabel as nib
# Read file
scan = nib.load('/path/to/stackOfimages.nii.gz')
# Get raw data
scan = scan.get_fdata()
print(scan.shape)
(128, 128, 100)
```

The images were in 2D png format, which I converted to nii.gz to make one 3D image, and now I want to convert them back to png format. because my model is a 2D model I want to feed the model with a stack of slices (each 100 slice for one person) rather than one image at a time. as shown in the figure below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
...
for plane in range(scan.shape[2]):
    p = scan[:,:,plane].astype(np.uint8)
    img = Image.fromarray(p)
    img.save( f'plane{plane}.png' )
```

Comment: thanks Tim but that save each image alone I want to convert all the slices inside scan as one image

Comment: How do you intend to combine the slices?  You didn't specify that.

Comment: That doesn't help.  A CT scan consists of a stack of 2D images that make up a 3D representation, but you can't store 3D information in a PNG.  It just isn't possible.